# Remove previously added active class and add to current

Tags: jquery

Need solution to solve simple logic on return function.

Below scripts works fine with slidejs plugin.

Addclass active works fine based on the current index value. But, its not removing previously added "active" class. have to add only to current li.. remove from others.

Please give me a solution to remove previously added "active" class.

**HTML**

```
<ul class="carousel-thumb">
    <li class="carousel-thumb--content">
        <a href="#" class="custom-item" data-item="0">
            <div class="carousel-thumb--image">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/63x63" class="pinit" alt="Please pin it" title="Please pin it">
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="carousel-thumb--content">
        <a href="#" class="custom-item" data-item="0">
            <div class="carousel-thumb--image">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/63x63" class="pinit" alt="Please pin it" title="Please pin it">
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**JS:**

```
_setSpecialsActive = function (number) {
    var $element, current;
    $element = $(this.element);
    this.data = $.data(this);
    current = number > -1 ? number : this.data.current;
    $(".active", $element).removeClass("active");
    return $(".carousel-thumb li:eq(" + current + ")").addClass("active");           
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand the function, but try to replace

```
$(".active", $element).removeClass("active");
```

on

```
$(".carousel-thumb li.active").removeClass('active');
```

Comment: Thanks for notify this!!